# Add expression db_select

Tags: database

What is the corresponding alternative in Drupal 7 for the following query

```
SELECT row_id,name,email, COUNT(name) AS name_count
FROM tn_api_users 
GROUP BY name
HAVING  (name_count > 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

That would need a combination of [`SelectQuery::addExpression()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7), and [`SelectQuery::having()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Ahaving/7), e.g.

```
$query = db_select('tn_api_users', 'u')
  ->fields('u', array('row_id', 'name', 'email'))
  ->groupBy('name')
  ->having('name_count > 1');

$query->addExpression('COUNT(name)', 'name_count');
```

Output:

```
SELECT u.row_id AS row_id, u.name AS name, u.email AS email, COUNT(name) AS name_count
FROM 
{tn_api_users} u
GROUP BY name
HAVING  (name_count > 1)
```

Comment: wow, that was fast !..... 
Thanks Clive.
The following query will give me the result of the persons with same "name".
Any idea how can I display all the records ?

Comment: Hmmm not too sure, but what about adding `->groupBy('row_id')` to the chain before the `name` group by? That would probably ruin your counting though. It's going to be tricky to get individual results if you're grouping the query on that column

Comment: It is a bit tricky indeed,
Unfortunately `code`->groupBy('row_id')`code` didn't work out.
I will just create an array and it will be two-step process. Thanks again !

Comment: Not very relevant to this question but still I find this web service http://jonduell.com/sql-parser to be very useful to build db_select() statements for given query.

Comment: @Sivaji That tools a great idea, unfortunately it fails for the query given in this question

Comment: @Clive, yes :( but mostly works though!